# SignalR with Chroniton

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm using chroniton to run my jobs. Also those jobs need to send message to SignalR clients which is grouped. But any how it is not sending.

Here is my job

```
namespace Logic.Logics
{
    public class JobLogic : IJobLogic
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext;

        public JobLogic(
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext,
        )
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            this.hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public void UpdateCredidJob()
        {
            this.unitOfWork.User.DecreaseCredit();
            this.NotifiyVehicles();
        }

        private void NotifiyVehicles() {

            var vehicles = this.unitOfWork.Vehicle.GetAll();
            foreach(Vehicle v in vehicles) {
                Vehicle vehicle = this.unitOfWork.Vehicle.GetByLicensePlate(v.LicensePlate);
                VehicleViewModel vm = Mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(vehicle);
                this.hubContext.Clients.Group("OwnVehicle"+vm.LicensePlate).SendAsync("ReceiveVehicle",vm).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

scheduling the job with chroniton and adding signalR in Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        ...
        services.AddSignalR(o=>{
            o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
    
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var singularity = Singularity.Instance;
        singularity.Start();
        singularity.ScheduleJob(
            new CronSchedule("0 0 0 * * * *"),
            new SimpleJob(
                dt=>{
                    IJobLogic jobRunner = (IJobLogic) serviceProvider.GetService<IJobLogic>();
                    jobRunner.DailyCredidJob();
                }
            ),
            false
            );
    ...
    }
    
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, PostgreSqlContext postgreSqlContext)
   {
    ...
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
           endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/my-hub");
       });
    ...
    }
```

As you see I'm sending message to a group which start with OwnVehicle and clients invokes JoinOwnVehicle in order to joint that group.

```
public class MyHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
{
        ...
        public async Task JoinOwnVehicle() {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "OwnVehicle"+this.RequestedVehicle.LicensePlate);
        }
        ...
}
```

But job can not send message to group clients. I'm sure that clients can join to groups because when I try to send message in a controller it works.

Probably DI doesn't work properly, I'm doing a mistake.

Can you help me about this issue?

Details

I'm using .NET Core 5.0 and Chroniton version is 1.0.3.3